# How do I scale specific points while leaving other points alone?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG that was created with a single poly which is used for an anchor border. A problem I'm running into is that I would like the button to support variable content - allowing the button to resize horizontally as necessary to fit, while constraining the angle of the side lines.

I can't seem to figure out if I need to somehow deal with splitting the original poly, adjusting the viewBox, or what. We're stumped.

The inline SVG I'm using is fairly basic:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.btn {
  width: 198px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 41px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 41px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s; }
  .btn.btnFluid {
    width: auto; }
    .btn.btnFluid svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 41px; }
  .btn svg polygon {
    fill: #000;
    transition: fill 0.3s ease;
    stroke: #002b5d;
    stroke-width: 2; }
  .btn:hover {
    color: #000; }
    .btn:hover svg polygon {
      stroke: #000;
      fill: #FFF; }
  .btn span {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px; }

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="btn-svg" viewBox="0 0 386.16 80">
    <polygon points="346.14 78 40.02 78 3.19 2 382.97 2 346.14 78"></polygon>
   </svg>
  <span>Read More</span>
</a>
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="btn btnFluid">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="btn-svg" viewBox="0 0 386.16 80" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="346.14 78 40.02 78 3.19 2 382.97 2 346.14 78"></polygon>
  </svg>
  <span>A much longer cta button label</span>
</a>
```

I have created an editable demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/32wcq1zr/1/ -- compare the side edge angle of the first button versus the second button. Ideally, I'd like to have the functionality of the second button but with a consistent angle of the side lines.

Answer (score 2):

With this particular shape, the other options presented here (using `pseudo` elements or `masks`) are better solutions. However, here's a good alternative for more complex shapes.

---

CSS `border-image` has been around for quite a while, has [reasonably good support](https://caniuse.com/#search=border-image), **AND allows for 9-slice scaling**.

9-slice scaling allows you to decide "how" each section of an image scales by breaking an image into quadrants representing all 4 corners, 4 sides & the center.

You can use `border-image` with either an image or SVG, but an image is much more straight forward. Chirs Coyer has a [good overview](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/).

**Here's an example using your shape**

*Note: it helps if you use an image with dimensions that make math easy*

[image] (100px x 40px with the bottom inset 20px)

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 20px solid black;
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8TC6.png);
  border-image-slice: 0 20% fill;
  border-image-width: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">short</a>

<a href="#">much longer text that causes things to scale</a>
```

**And a more complex shape to show how it works:**

[image]

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
  margin: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0 10px;
 border: 20px solid;
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUwi4.png);
 border-image-slice: 15 fill;
 border-image-width: auto;
 border-image-repeat: round;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">short</a>

<a href="#">much longer text that causes things to scale</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution to your problem. Instead of using SVG this can ve done with transparent borders and the text into an ::before / ::after

```css
.button {
  --h:50;
  width: 198px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: calc(var(--h) * 1px) solid black;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
  position:relative;
}

.button::before {
  content: "Read More";
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height:calc(var(--h) * 1px);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--h) * -1px);
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:calc(var(--h) * 1px);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button.long{width:300px}

.button.long::before{content:"A much longer cta button label"}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button long"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Stretchy" SVGs like that you are after are, in general, not possible.

But in certain circumstances it is possible to achieve, using some tricks with the `<use>` and `<mask>` elements.

How this works is that we split the button into two shapes. One for the left end (`#left`), and one for the middle and right end (`#right`).  The right one is made very long so that it can accommodate a range of button sizes.  The right part is positioned against the right hand end of the SVG, and masked so that it doesn't cover the left hand part.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.btn {
  width: 198px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 41px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 41px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s; }
  .btn.btnFluid {
    width: auto; }
    .btn.btnFluid svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 41px; }
  .btn svg .highlight {
    fill: #000;
    transition: fill 0.3s ease;
    stroke: #002b5d;
    stroke-width: 2; }
  .btn:hover {
    color: #000; }
    .btn:hover svg .highlight {
      stroke: #000;
      fill: #FFF; }
  .btn span {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px; }

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <svg class="btn-svg" width="100%">
    <defs>
      <polyline id="left" points="21,1, 1,1, 20,40, 21,40"/>
      <polyline id="right" points="-1500,1, -1,1, -20,40, -1500,40"/>
      <mask id="mask-right">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
        <rect width="20" height="100%" fill="black"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <g class="highlight" mask="url(#mask-right)">
      <use xlink:href="#right" x="100%"/>
    </g>
    <use class="highlight" xlink:href="#left"/>
  </svg>
  <span>Read More</span>
</a>
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="btn btnFluid">
  <svg class="btn-svg" width="100%">
    <defs>
      <polyline id="left2" points="21,1, 1,1, 20,40, 21,40"/>
      <polyline id="right2" points="-1500,1, -1,1, -20,40, -1500,40"/>
      <mask id="mask-right2">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
        <rect width="20" height="100%" fill="black"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <g class="highlight" mask="url(#mask-right2)">
      <use xlink:href="#right" x="100%"/>
    </g>
    <use class="highlight" xlink:href="#left2"/>
  </svg>
  <span>A much longer cta button label</span>
</a>
```